# Is there acausal behaviour with dependency cycles in the relaxed memory model of C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model

Assume that `x` and `y` are atomic integers initialized with 0.

Now, Thread A runs the following code:

```
if (x.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 1) {
    y.store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

and Thread B runs this code:

```
if (y.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 1) {
    x.store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

Is it possible, in C++, to reach a situation where `(x == 1 and y == 1)`? If it *is* possible, why?

I have seen that claim in https://people.mpi-sws.org/~viktor/slides/2014-07-ec2.pdf (the dependency cycle section).

Comment: Are you just asking because you are curious? Or is it a homework/exam/interview question? Or is there some other problem that makes you ask this question? If it's some other problem, then it would be better to ask about it directly instead.

Comment: I wonder whether the slides actually meant to compare the loads with 0. That could be a more interesting case. … ah, no, they appear to be making some argument that the C11 relaxed memory order violates causality (monotonicity?) because there is no synchronisation at all specified…

Comment: @JonasWielicki: The standard puts constraints on implementations. The relaxed memory order specification doesn't _force_ implementations to violate causality. Implementations may of course violate causality, where unconstrained by the standard and reality.

Comment: It would be better to post a compilable example.

Answer (score 4):

Good question!

These are known as "out of thin air" values, since there's no source for the value 1. These were overlooked in C++11, noted by paper [N3710](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3710.html) and banned in C++14.

As N3710 notes,

> No known implementations actually produce such results.

Comment: @최범석: Yes, according to N3710. And C++14 ensures it's also impossible on future implementations

Comment: i think i'm almost there.. and furthermore, there's no known implementations that produce the result x== 1 and y == 1 in c++11?

Comment: @최범석: Well, not entirely. The problem is that C++ has a somewhat _relaxed_ view on causality. C++ only demands that implementations appear to behave _as if_ they obey the requirements in the standard, but for performance reasons this might differ. In practice, instructions may be reordered for speed and/or execute in parallel, as long as a C++ programs can't spot it using pure C++. And since the C++ standard doesn't _fully_ specify causality, implementations may take advantage of that. There is a lot of causality as a result of _sequenced-before_ relations, but not with `memory_order_relaxed`

Answer (score 1):

Often with these questions the way to answer it is, beside understanding what atomic variables are, imagine every possible scenario.

What is an atomic operation? It's an operation that can't be split. It's either done or not done.

Given that, consider every possible scenario.

- Can either of the cases enter the if condition? No. Because both variables are `0`, and nothing will turn them into `1`.

Sounds trivial, but that's all your possibilities. The more important question is, why would x or y become `1` in the first place? Based on what you provided. There's no reason.

---

EDIT:

My only comment on that presentation you linked is that it's *just wrong*. To prove it, I used this program, and the cases never entered the if conditions. Anyone reading this, please confirm what I'm saying because I may be wrong. I ran this program for a few minutes and nothing happened `(gcc (Debian 6.2.1-5) 6.2.1 20161124)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_int x,y;

void call1()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
        {
            std::cout<<"I'm in!"<<std::endl;
            y.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }
    }
}

void call2()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
        {
            std::cout<<"I'm also in!"<<std::endl;
            x.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    x.store(0);
    y.store(0);

    std::thread t1(call1);
    std::thread t2(call2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. edited my question. the dependency cycle section in the added link page indicates that it can be possible (x == 1 , y == 1) and i don't know why.

Comment: @최범석 How about now?

Comment: my computer uses intel cpu , so i can't test it because relaxed memory ordering doesn't work.

Comment: @최범석 I'm using intel too, but I really think this information is purely wrong. Not allowing synchronization means that ordering is not deterministic, but in that example there's no ordering at all that will let you enter the loop. Usually in such simple cases you can show the path that leads to race conditions, but it's not present here.

Comment: I think the presentation argues on a mathematical level. They may not be wrong, but at least they’re not very *useful* in actual hardware. Because actual hardware obeys causality, which needs to break down for the program to actually enter the x==1 && y==1 case. (Although I wonder whether it might be the case that causality breaks if we have speculative execution in the play.)

Comment: @JonasWielicki Causality? Like the effect before the cause? hmmmm... Unless we use quantum computers where the Heisenberg uncertainty principle is significant, I don't see why this is possible.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist For x==1 || y==1 (which is a precondition for x==1 && y==1), it is required that any of the if branches is entered, right? This requires, in itself, however that the respective other variable is 1. I cannot see how this can happen when observed causality is preserved and the variables are initialised to 0, but I may be overlooking something. Unless we have visible side-effects of speculative execution, where a CPU core "decides" to evaluate the if branch and only afterwards check the condition. In that case the other core could see the 1 and we end up with x==1 && y==1.

Comment: Maybe causality is the wrong term. It *appears* to me that the slides call this concept "monotonicity". From a quick read-up on the concept, it doesn’t appear to me to be sufficient (according to Wikipedia) Tanenbaum defines monotonicity to be that "any successive read operation on x by that process will always return that same value or a more recent value". For example, for *x* to become 1, *y* must be read as 1. However, *y* can only ever be 1 if *x* is already one. I cannot see how this can happen when causality is preserved (and x and y are initialised to 0 of course).

Comment: @JonasWielicki I agree with you for the most part. Though that part with CPUs evaluating the if condition first is something I never heard about before. One more thing to learn.

Comment: I know it's a hard question to answer correctly, but still -1, wrong. You can't prove this by experimentation, that's fairly clear. More importantly, your initial analysis hinges on the (unspoken) assumption that there is an (unspecified) order in which the statements happen. That's not true for relaxed memory order.

Comment: @MSalters "More importantly, your initial analysis hinges on the (unspoken) assumption that there is an (unspecified) order in which the statements happen. That's not true for relaxed memory order". Could you please explain what exactly is not true for relaxed memory order? I read *a lot* about the C++11 memory model, but I don't consider myself an expert there. So please explain.

Comment: With a relaxed memory order (in general, without sequencing), two threads may have different views of which instructions happen in which order. Your scenario analysis "Can either of the cases enter the if condition? No. Because both variables are 0, and nothing will turn them into 1." fails to analyze the possibility that the store in one thread is reordered _from the perspective of the other thread_.

Comment: @MSalters But the other thread looks at the other thread *through memory*, not through the instructions happening in the other processor. Why would the other thread see the value changed to 1 if the first thread never does that?

Comment: That sounds entirely reasonable, but the Standard describes thread synchronization in terms of sequenced-before operations on instructions, _not_ in terms of shared memory.

Comment: @MSalters I'm having a hard time understanding this. I have some reading to do.

Comment: @최범석 This is what I learned here. I think you're right, otherwise I got this whole thing wrong.